Check if functions in a class start with a regex
I'm using Visual Studio, C++. I want to make sure that every single function in a large class (called ExampleClass) starts off with a call to a macro (EXAMPLE_MACRO();).
I figured I could do this by just using this regex:
ExampleClass::[\s\S]*?{\s*\n\s*(?!.*EXAMPLE_MACRO)

Unfortunately, the regex is registering functions as matches when they have other "{" characters in the function beyond the first one.
Anyone have any ideas on how I could tackle this? Here are some example functions to test with...
bool ExampleClass::ExampleFunction1(
   const bool ExampleParam) const
{
   // No macro call, this should be a match.
}

void ExampleClass::ExampleFunction2(const bool ExampleParam)
{
   EXAMPLE_MACRO();
   // Macro call exists, this should NOT be a match.
   if()
   {
   }
}

bool ExampleClass::ExampleFunction3(
   const bool ExampleParam1,
   const bool ExampleParam2)
{
   EXAMPLE_MACRO();
   // Macro call exists, this should NOT be a match.
}


[\s\S]*? will match as far as necessary in order to match the rest of the pattern. Making it non-greedy doesn't prevent it from going past the end of the function.

I've gotten as far as this... but it still is saying EXAMPLE_MACRO is a match.
(ExampleClass::[\s\S]?{\n).(?!EXAMPLE_MACRO)

Some issues:

[\s\S]*? could include { characters in its match. This can happen when the regex has to backtrack because the negative look ahead assertion isn't true. Instead you should better explicitly disallow {. As the input seems to be C++ code, also think of method declarations that don't have a body: you might not want to have matches cross over to the next method declaration, and forbid ; as well, with [^{;]*.

\s*\n\s* can result in a useless amount of backtracking because \n is also matched by \s. Moreover, as C++ code doesn't need those newline characters, you shouldn't require them here. Just use \s*.

The .* in (?!.*EXAMPLE_MACRO) could include opening braces as well -- if the source has not used line breaks to nicely format the code. Instead, require that those characters are all white space.

EXAMPLE_MACRO will also match EXAMPLE_MACRO_WITH_MORE_TEXT which is probably not what you want, so make sure to also match the opening parenthesis.

Some regex flavours require that an opening brace (intended as a literal character) must be escaped. It doesn't hurt to do it anyway, also where this is not required when there is no ambiguity.


Here is a correction:
ExampleClass::[^{]*\{(?!\s*EXAMPLE_MACRO\s*\()

Be aware of limitations. This tests that EXAMPLE_MACRO( does not occur immediately after the opening brace with optional white space. If the opening brace happens to be followed by /* or // -- indicating a comment -- there is no check that EXAMPLE_MACRO( might still follow after that comment.
